# Objective-C: most efficient way to find the quadrant of an angle in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, trigonometry

What is the most efficient way to find the quadrant of an angle given in Objective-C (assuming that the boundary angles 0, 90, 270, 360 etc. all fall within a quadrant) ?

Comment: @hanshirse Hi I would appreciate it if you reopened this question as I've edited it so it works better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any magic functions.
Full circle contains 2*Pi radians and 4 quadrants.
So just divide angle by Pi/2 and make floor rounding to get 0..3 quadrant numbering (add 1 if 1..4 is needed)

Python example. Note that integer modulo operation `% 4` provides "angle normalisation" so function works with large and negative angles
(Swift `%` does not work similar according to [table here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), so you might need to make something like `return ((floor(2.0 * angle / math.pi) % 4 + 4)  %4`)

```
import math
def quadrant(angle):
    return math.floor(2.0 * angle / math.pi) % 4

print(quadrant(math.pi/4))
print(quadrant(math.pi/4 + math.pi))
print(quadrant(math.pi/4 - math.pi))

0
2
2
```

Comment: Have to also get the initial angle between 0 and 2PI by subtracting or adding 2PI (depending on if negative or not). Yeah this is easy and I got downvoted but there is enough little detail in it that I'd rather just obtain some tried and tested code instead of reinviting the wheel again.